# Gensim ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

Tags: python, gensim

SOLVED: It seems that referencing my toUse variable does not work as an acceptable file path input. Changing it to the true path fixed the problem.

I'm relatively new to Python and am biting off more than I can chew but I don't understand how I keep getting this error in my code. It's just a simple I/O operation on closed file yet I don't know how my file is a closed file, error is derived from the corpora.MmCorpus.serialize() statement shown after this block of code.

```
from gensim import corpora
temporary=open('C:\\Users\\A\\Horror and Suspense\\data\\inUse.txt','r')
toUse=open('C:\\Users\\A\\Horror and Suspense\\data\\parsing.txt','r+')
for line in temporary:
    toUse.write(line)
temporary.close()
corpus=corpora.textcorpus.TextCorpus(input=toUse)
corpora.MmCorpus.serialize('C:\\Users\\A\\Horror and 
Suspense\\data\\corpora.mm',corpus)
```

Here's the error:

```
runfile('C:/Users/A/Horror and Suspense/System1/useFiles.py',         wdir='C:/Users/A/Horror and Suspense/System1')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-37-ccfa33041487>", line 1, in <module>
runfile('C:/Users/A/Horror and Suspense/System1/useFiles.py', wdir='C:/Users/A/Horror and Suspense/System1')

  File "C:\Users\A\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 710, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\A\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 101, in execfile
exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/A/Horror and Suspense/System1/useFiles.py", line 10, in <module>
corpora.MmCorpus.serialize('C:\\Users\\A\\Horror and Suspense\\data\\corpora.mm',corpus)

  File "C:\Users\A\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\corpora\indexedcorpus.py", line 93, in serialize
offsets = serializer.save_corpus(fname, corpus, id2word, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\A\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\corpora\mmcorpus.py", line 51, in save_corpus
fname, corpus, num_terms=num_terms, index=True, progress_cnt=progress_cnt, metadata=metadata

  File "C:\Users\A\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\matutils.py", line 723, in write_corpus
    for docno, doc in enumerate(corpus):

  File "C:\Users\A\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\corpora\textcorpus.py", line 184, in __iter__
    for text in self.get_texts():

  File "C:\Users\A\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\corpora\textcorpus.py", line 250, in get_texts
for line in lines:

  File "C:\Users\A\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\corpora\textcorpus.py", line 193, in getstream
with utils.file_or_filename(self.input) as f:

  File "C:\Users\A\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\utils.py", line 148, in file_or_filename
input.seek(0)

ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

Comment: I suppose (though  the error is in the `write()` statement. Is anything being written at all? or is the error being generated the first time `write()` is called? Does `serialize` also write to disk, and is it possible that is what is generating the error?

Comment: the write statement writes to a file, the error come from the serialize statement

Comment: I've never used gensim. It appears to me that toUse is positioned at end-of-file (because the last thing that was done to it was a write). You could try putting `toUse.seek(0)` just before the `corpus=` statement to reposition it to beginning-of-file.

Comment: Bill, I just tried that and it still returns the io error, seems like a gensim problem maybe. I'm not familiar enough with this to know

Comment: Paste in the error with a full stack trace.